# `instead of update` trigger: How to distinguish when user provides new value for the column and when does not?

Tags: postgresql

Inside the trigger `NEW.field` value is always has `<some value>`  despite on that column appears on `SET` list of UPDATE statement or does not:

```
UPDATE test SET name = 'abc', field = <some value>;
UPDATE test SET name = 'abc';
```

For both queries in trigger I will get `field` with `<some value>`.

Is there a way to distinguish these two queries from inside trigger?

Comment: `DEFAULT` values are only applied during `INSERT`, not for an UPDATE

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: fixed question

Comment: You can define an update trigger so, that it only fires if certain columns are target of the update using `UPDATE OF <columns>` as event. Maybe you can use that somehow.

Comment: @stickybit: same problem exists also for `instead of insert` trigger. And there is no `INSERT OF <columns>` =(  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6787bf89d1eaf1413983307e30ed1500)

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could just compare the NEW value to the OLD.  If it's different, you know the field was set.

Unless you wanted to capture when there was an update to the field, even if the field value did not change, I would think this captures it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_update_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

  if (OLD.field is null and NEW.field is not null or
      OLD.field is not null and NEW.field is null or
      OLD.field != NEW.field) then
    -- do something
  end if;

  return NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: You can simplify the IF condition to `if (old.column is distinct from new.column)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - wow, never knew that existed.  Fantastic, thanks

Comment: yes, I want to `to capture when there was an update to the field, even if the field value did not change`. But how `OLD.field != NEW.field` recognizes the update if OLD/NEW values are same?

Comment: Yeah, that was always a possibility...  In that case, I would go with the solution @stickybit suggested.